# Dynamically change shader syntax with the help of C++

Tags: c++, opengl, shaders, pipeline

I'm starting with the programmable pipeline and the shaders in C++ for OpenGL 3.0+, i would love to be able to change some settings on the fly, for example replacing a function with another function, supposing that i have a shader with an operation like

```
var = A + B
```

my goal is replacing `+` with any other operation on the fly with my C++ program, maybe with a GUI, but in general terms with C++, the problem is that until now i'm able to run a shader only after compiling it, so i have something like a static approach.

The same goal applies to the values of the vars that i would also like to change through C++.

It's possible with a programmable pipeline? I'm not interested in performance, just if is possible for the C++ to dynamically communicate and exchange data with the OpenGL pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

You can certainly create a new shader string, compile it into a new shader object, and link it into a new program object. But you can't *modify* an existing shader's source code.

If you just want to change what gets called when, you can use an `if` statement in your shader based on `uniform` variables. Though this can get out of hand if you do it a lot.

GLSL 4.00 adds the ability to define [multiple subroutines in a shader](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_subroutine.txt) and dynamically (meaning, post-linking) pick which one to execute. But that's about it.

Comment: I would like to write my small utility with a GUI a find out what changes when changing a particular operation in a shader, like adding vs subtracting, or change a particular value with the help of a slider for example, everything in real time and dynamically. A very basic shader designer using widget from a GUI.

Comment: @user827992: It doesn't matter whether the changes come from a GUI or what have you. If you want to change your shader, you must compile a *new* shader. You can change uniform variables with the API, but the shader itself is *immutable*.

Comment: to what API are you referring to?

Comment: @user827992: OpenGL. That's what we're talking about, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but i was thinking about a specific subset only for changing variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption: You have shader code in the variable.**

You actually can do something that accomplishes this.
Change the source code of the given shader, recompile it and run the new one.

My use of this :

```
char s1[] = "#version 430 core\n\
                #define SIZE ";
char *s2 = new char[sizeof(itoa(256, s2, 10))];
char computeShaderSource[] = {"rest of the shader code here"}
char *finalSource = new char[sizeof(s1) + sizeof(s2)+ sizeof(computeShaderSource)];
sprintf(finalSource,"%s%s\n%s",s1,s2,computeShaderSource);
```

I really dont guarantee that this is the best practices.

From the performance point of view, it will depend on how many times you will change this.